# Topology: Envisioning a Particular Subspace

Tags: general-topology

For the final week of my proof-writing class, my professor decided to dabble in topology since that is her favorite topic in math. However, I am having a bit of trouble understanding one of the homework questions we were given.

For the following subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, determine the interior points, whether or not the set is open, and whether or not the set is connected:

$\mathbb{R}^3$- {$0$}

I am having trouble envisioning what this subspace is exactly. I believe that once I understand the space I should be able to answer the questions. Is this a trick question, where $\mathbb{R}^3$- {$0$} is the same thing as saying $\mathbb{R}^3$? Or does this mean that any point we select in $\mathbb{R}^3$ cannot contain a zero, meaning we exclude the $xy$, $xz$ and $yz$ planes? These are just some ideas I have come up with... any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing $0$ here refers to the additive identity of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$: the point $(0, 0, 0)$. It should be clear from context, or else it's not a well-formed question.

Comment: This only means the entire euclidean space, except the point $ \{0,0,0 \}. $ It is customary to write, for vector spaces, $0$ as the vector $\textbf{0}$

Comment: Thank you both! I did not know that you could write $(0,0,0)$ in that way.

Comment: When discussing an algebraic structure  with an additive identity it is common to call that identity $0.$ Even though, when V is a vector space over a field F, there are (usually) two zeroes: The additive identity of F and the additive identity of V. We even use the same symbol  $+$  for addition of members of F and for addition of members of V, although theses are (usually) two different operations on different domains.